# Why they are not the same?

Tags: javascript, dom

This statement:

```
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("div")).forEach(function (item,index){console.log (item===[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("div"))[index])});
```

gives all true results.
but:

```
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("div"))===[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("div"));
```

gives false result.
Why?

Comment: Please format your code. It is extremely difficult to read in its current state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second case you are trying to compare two Arrays where as in the first case you are comparing individual elements. That's why the results are different.

Comparing the individual elements of the array and comparing two array are not equal. For example this javascript function checks array equality

```
 function arraysEqual(a, b) {
  if (a === b) return true;
  if (a == null || b == null) return false;
  if (a.length != b.length) return false;

  // If you don't care about the order of the elements inside
  // the array, you should sort both arrays here.

  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    if (a[i] !== b[i]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

and now when you call this function using

```
arraysEqual([].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("div")), [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("div")))
```

that results in true.

Comment: The 2 Arrays have same elements,but why they are different?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can put it is:

```
var a = [];
var b = [];

a === b // false
```

Arrays are objects in javascript. If you instantiate two arrays, they are not `===` to each other. However, if you go element by element and have the same elements, then yes they are equal because you are comparing the same object.